# Writing to a TextureCube in Unordered Access View in Compute Shader

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, rendering, hlsl

I'm trying to use a compute shader to generate an irradiance map from an existing environment map. I want to write to a TextureCube object in an Unordered Access View (UAV) to store the eventual output, but I do not think this is allowed.

What should I do for storing the result of my compute shader? It will be reading from a TextureCube in the SRV and i want to write to another TextureCube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it is impossible to write to a TextureCube object in the shader, so will instead be using a RWTextureArray in the unordered access view.